# Read rss feeds with c# mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, rss

this is my first post.
So I have this problem and I'm very new to this language or c#.

I have a model that reads the news rss, then using the same index controller I have to pass it to a view.

This is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Fantacalcio.Web.Areas.Admin.Models
{
    public class FeedGazzetta
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string PubDate { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReadFeedGazzetta
    {
        public static List<FeedGazzetta> GetFeed()
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            var xmlData = client.DownloadString("http://www.gazzetta.it/rss/Calcio.xml");

            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

            var GazzettaUpdates = (from story in xml.Descendants("item")
                             select new FeedGazzetta
                             {
                                 Title = ((string)story.Element("title")),
                                 Link = ((string)story.Element("link")),
                                 Description = ((string)story.Element("description")),
                                 PubDate = ((string)story.Element("pubDate")),
                                 Image = ((string)story.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url"))
                             }).Take(10).ToList();

            return GazzettaUpdates;
        }
    }

}
```

My controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            IndexAdminVm model = new IndexAdminVm();

            //List<FeedGazzetta> ListaNotizie = new List<FeedGazzetta>();
            model.ListaNotizie = ReadFeedGazzetta.GetFeed();
            return View(model);
        }
```

My ViewModel is this:

```
public class IndexAdminVm
    {
        public List<FeedGazzetta> ListaNotizie { get; set; }
    }
```

And my view is this:

```
@model List<Fantacalcio.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.IndexAdminVm>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<h2>Home</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.ListaNotizie.FirstOrDefault().Title <br />
    @Html.Raw(item.ListaNotizie.FirstOrDefault().Description) <br />
    @item.ListaNotizie.FirstOrDefault().Image <br />
    @Convert.ToDateTime(item.ListaNotizie.FirstOrDefault().PubDate) <br />
    @item.ListaNotizie.FirstOrDefault().Link <br />
    <br /><br />
}
```

In compiling do not get any error, but when I check on the web, I get this from the view:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Fantacalcio.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.IndexAdminVm', but the dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List `1 [Fantacalcio.Web. Areas.Admin.Models.IndexAdminVm] '.**

What is wrong?

I hope I was clear :)
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing wrong model to View.
You pass single `IndexAdminVm` but expects List of this view models. You should change your view to this:

```
@model Fantacalcio.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.IndexAdminVm

...

@foreach (var item in Model.ListaNotizie)

...
```

Comment: Thank you so much

I have lost at least one hour for this thing.
Unfortunately there are still shod with this language

thanks again