# Error Reading RSS Feed using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, webclient

In referencing this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539828/read-rss-feeds-with-c-sharp-mvc4) I am receiving a `NullReferenceException` stating `Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.` I'm not sure how to fix this solution as I've followed the steps in my reference article.

Models

```
public class RssModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

}

public class ReadRssModel
{
    public static List<RssModel> GetRss()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();

        var xmlData = client.DownloadString("http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=msft,goog,aapl");

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

        var rssData = (from item in xml.Descendants("item")
                       select new RssModel
                       {
                           Title = ((string)item.Element("title")),
                           Link = ((string)item.Element("link")),
                           Description = ((string)item.Element("description")),

                           Image = ((string)item.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url"))
                       }).Take(20).ToList();

        return rssData;

    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class RssViewModel
{
    public List<RssModel> RssFeed { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return View();
        RssViewModel model = new RssViewModel();
        model.RssFeed = ReadRssModel.GetRss();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Index

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<h4>Feed</h4>

    @foreach (var item in Model.RssFeed)
    {
        @item.Title <br />
        @item.Description <br/>

    }

</div>
```

Comment: It is because there is no element `enclosure` in descendants of `item`.

Comment: So, I'm starting to understand this now that I'm pulling data successfully. There actually is no image available for each item element, only for the Channel element. So what I'm doing is actually pulling the item elements and NOT the channel elements. Can you suggest how to make the Link an actual hyperlink in the View?

Comment: WebClient implements IDisposable, you should [wrap your WebClient with a using clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have two layers of tags.  First the channel and then the items.  See code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication47
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=msft,goog,aapl");

            var results = xml.Descendants("channel").Select(x => new
            {
                Title = ((string)x.Element("title")),
                Link = ((string)x.Element("link")),
                Description = ((string)x.Element("description")),
                Image = ((string)x.Element("image").Element("url")),
                items = x.Elements("item").Take(20).Select(y => new {
                    title = (string)y.Element("title"),
                    link = (string)y.Element("link"),
                    description = (string)y.Element("description")
                }).ToList(),
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        }

    }
}
```