# Convert ForEach Loop to For Loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loops, razor

Currently I am looping through items in my ASP.NET MVC project, in my main Index page, and returning the results. What I'd like to do is limit this to only include the first 5 items, instead of every value available. I am brand new to Razor syntax and I am having a little trouble figuring out the correct implementation.

ForEach Loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RssFeed)
    {
        @item.Title <br />            
        @item.Description <br />
        <br />
    }
```

For Loop

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //How to call items?
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are introducing logic into your View.  Instead before the model is passed to the view, you should imited the results.

Comment: That is what i was worried about. Thanks for the insight. In my model I pull 50 results from a webrequest, and render those in the View in more than one page. The first page requires all items and the second page requires only 5. My implementation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544755/error-reading-rss-feed-using-linq-to-xml/32545308#32545308 . Could you suggest the best way to only return the first 5 results? Some sort of query within the Controller?

Comment: You question has no reference to 50 items....  did you mean 20?

Comment: Yes my apologies. 20 items.

Comment: Instead of the signature `GetRss()` change it to `GetRss(int modelCount)` and instead of `.Take(20)` use `.Take(modelCount)`.

Comment: This worked perfect with passing an integer count as an argument of GetRss in my Controller. Thanks this definitely gives me more insight into calling model information from the controller to update the view.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you should filter your items in the controller Action, btw you could do something Like this (and forget the for loop):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RssFeed.Take(5))
    {
        @item.Title   <br />            
        @item.Description <br />
       <br />
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a `RuntimeBinderException` on `Model.RssFeed.Take(5)` stating `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first five and a **for** loop something like:

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        @Model.RssFeed[i].Title <br />            
        @Model.RssFeed[i].Description <br />
        <br />
    }
```

This will give you the first 5, you have to setup some paging if you want the rest. This is also assuming you have more than 5 items in the list

Comment: I am getting a `RuntimeBinderException` on the first `Model.RssFeed[i]` stating `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`.

Comment: @Matthew make sure all the items in the list are populated and none are null or handle a null from your code