# How to Get Full RSS Article In ASP.NET MVC Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, rss

Currently I have accomplished with my introductory RSS reader MVC project a basic template whereby I am pulling in RSS articles from yahoo finance. This was exciting until i realized the items returned do not contain full text of the articles, just descriptions and a link back to the yahoo finance site. I'd like to find a way to pull in the entire article whereby i may click on the title of an article from a list in my Home page and then in my Article page I can read that whole article. A reference to my current implementation may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544755/error-reading-rss-feed-using-linq-to-xml?noredirect=1#comment53004146_32544755). A link to the yahoo finance RSS feed information is available [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html).

Comment: What do you expect from us? A code solution showing you how to do it? That's your job! Make an attempt to solve the issue. If you get stuck, *then* that might be an appropriate question.

Comment: What I'm wondering is if this can be implementing using this type of solution, and if so, how? I've seen sites that contain the full RSS feed after selecting on an article from the list, but I can't seem to find a way to pull the whole article and display it.

Comment: Seems straightforward to me. Look through their documentation. Do they have an API for retrieving the article text? If so, use that. If not, then you can retrieve the article text from their site manually (the C# equivalent of [CURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)ing a webpage). Obviously that's not preferable, but that may be how they're doing it.